# Retrieving height with FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg

I made the following command I use to get the height of a video:

```
ffprobe -v quiet -print_format compact=print_section=0:nokey=1:escape=csv -show_entries stream=height "source.mp4"
```

Sometimes it returns this:

```
360
(empty space)
(empty space)
```

Sometimes it returns this:

```
360
(empty space)
N/A
```

How can I get it to return just one line?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a different print format (or "writer"). The default, without the keys (`nk=1`) and wrapper (`nw=1`), appears to not add the extra space.

```
$ ffprobe -v error -of default=nk=1:nw=1 -show_entries stream=height input.mp4
  360
```

- [FFmpeg Wiki: FFprobe Tips](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/FFprobeTips)
- [FFprobe Documentation: Writers](https://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html#Writers)

Comment: Thanks, however for certain videos I still get the `N/A`. Whereas my old code produced `360\n\nN/A\n` the new one produces `360\nN/A\n` for the exact same video.

Comment: @pufAmuf Can you provide a short sample input file?